# prevent rounding of decimals when using currency string format

Tags: .net, string-formatting

I have some decimal data coming from an external service. I need to format the data to 2 decimal places as it is represents money, but if I use the standard C format, I rounds the number:

```
var x = 42.999m;

var y = string.Format("{0:C}", x);
```

This results in y containing £43.00. How can I have it round down to £42.99?

(Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180068/format-currency-without-rounding) is not the same)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a non-default rounding strategy, you'd need to do something like:

```
var x = 42.999m;

var y = string.Format("{0:C}", Math.Floor(x * 100) / 100);
```

`Math.Floor` rounds down; however it doesn't take a number of decimal places, so you have to force the 2 decimal place behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

although this question has been solved but i suggest you to use

```
var y = String.Format("{0:c3}",x);
// "{0:C3}" is for -123.456 ("C3", en-US) -> ($123.456)
```

[From here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)