# why DataBinder Eval value is rounded on aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have DiscountTotal variable with decimal type. Values are set on code behind the page, after page is loaded the values are rounded. If i use label control in the template then values don't get rounded.

```
 <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DiscountTotal","{0:C}")%>
```

Value 7610.3250D is being displayed as £7610.33. I like this to be displayed as £7610.32 or $7610.32 depending on logged in user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are formating with `{0:C}`, the currency formatter. Remove it and try again.

Comment: @user1263981 Try formatting as `{£0:n2}`, it is a little ugly but should do the trick.

Comment: If you still want to use the currency formatter to get the user localization, but flooring rather than ceiling, then I recommend you to do that before you send to the View. Please see [this related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042262/prevent-rounding-of-decimals-when-using-currency-string-format)