# Xamarin Forms: Problem with TwoWay Binding and StringFormat

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, binding, string-formatting

I've an `Entry` where `Text` property is binded to a `double` in my view model. This binding is a `TwoWay` and has a `StringFormat` for 2 decimal places.

Here is the code:

```
<Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding ViewModel.Weight, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{0:F2}'}" />
```

It looks like if there is no problem at all, but there is one:

When I start typing into this `Entry` the cursor moves to the end, so I've to move it back to the position where I want to type.

It's a really nasty behavior. If I remove the `StringFormat` everything goes perfect!

Ideas??

[image]

Comment: If it is okay, I would put a delay before I would format. Say if user stops typing then after 300 miliseconds or somewhere I would format. Currently you are formatting while typing and string formatter is trying to convert value as decimal which changes the cursor position as well.
Or else, You can implement your own numeric text entry control

Comment: Can you please add a Gif to show the nasty behavior? It seems it doesn't happen on my side or am I miss something?

Comment: Hi @Deczaloth, I stopped this working branch due to a priority change. I'll retake it next week and I'll let you all know.

Comment: Just curious about how did you finally solved this issue... Could you post your solution? That would help others!

Answer (score 1):

Really nasty behavior... hey wait, what about behaviors!

I tried to implement your case by following the nice guide the good old @AdamPedley left us before he left Xamarin...

https://xamarinhelp.com/masked-entry-in-xamarin-forms/

Nevertheless, i realized that even that nice made behavior presents that nasty behavior.

The only option i see, that could perform well is applying the format after the user left the entry (when the `Unfocused` event is fired!)

To do this you have to subscribe to the `Unfocused` events:

```
<Entry x:Name="entry" 
       Keyboard="Numeric" 
       Text="{Binding Weight, Mode=TwoWay}"
       Unfocused="entry_Unfocused"/>
```

And then in the code behind

```
private void entry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    if (double.TryParse(entry.Text, out double result))
    {
        entry.Text = String.Format("{0:F2}", Math.Floor(result * 100) / 100);
    }
}
```

**NOTE: By default the String.Format rounds the result. Here i used the solution given in [a SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042262/prevent-rounding-of-decimals-when-using-currency-string-format) to avoid that nasty behavior and cut the decimals up to the second place... but you can just do what you want! (I found out that automatically performing that rounding can lead to the issue i describe in [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58847342/setter-of-property-bound-to-entry-text-loops-indefenetly)!)**

Comment: If we just want to display the entry value without rounding, the better way is just to use like that?  `entry.Text = String.Format("{0:F2}", result);`