# Setter of property bound to Entry.Text loops infinitely

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, double, string.format

This is driving me crazy. I have been looking for the source of the issue for hours, but i am starting to suspect this is not an issue in my logic... Maybe i am wrong.

---

### Issue description

I have a simple **Entry**. Its **Text** property is bound to a property with type **double** in a **ViewModel**. At the same time i subscribe to the `Unfocused` **Event** whose **EventHandler** simply sets the `entry.Text` property to `"1.0"` (actually i can reproduce the issue for x.y0, that is any decimal whose final digit is 0). If now i write in the **Entry** anything (except "1" or "1." or "1.0"!!!) and leave the **Entry** (by tapping outside or taping on Done) so that `Unfocused` is fired, the **App** becomes unresponsive.

**Note:** I know that it sounds a bit strange to set `entry.Text = 1.0` in the event handler. The truth is that i came across this issue by trying to format the `entry.Text` value as follows.

```
if (double.TryParse(entry.Text, out double result))
{
    entry.Text = String.Format("{0:F2}", result);
}
```

There `String.Format` tries to round the decimal to two decimals. If i give `6.999` the expected value should be `7.00`, but the **App** becomes unresponsive instead.

---

### Steps to reproduce the issue

1. Create blank **Xamarin.Forms** proyect.
2. Remove default **Label** in *MainPage.xaml* file to include following **Entry**, instead:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Entry Text="{Binding Weight}"
    Unfocused="entry_Unfocused"/>
</StackLayout>
```

3. In the code behind add the following **EventHandler** and set the `BindingContext` property of the page as follows:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        BindingContext = new viewmodel();
    }

    private void entry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Entry)sender).Text = "1.0";
    }

}
```

4. Create the **ViewModel** like:

```
public class viewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public viewmodel()
    {
    }

    private double _Weight;
    public double Weight
    {
        get => _Weight;
        set
        {
            if (_Weight != value)
            {
                _Weight = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

5. Run the App and type anything into the **Entry**.
6. Leave the **Entry** so that `Unfocused` is fired.

---

### My System configuration:

- Visual Studio v. 16.3.8
- Xamarin.Forms 4.2.0.709249
- Android 8

---

Could anyone explain what is going on here, and anyway to work around this issue?

Comment: I'd assume that the Unfocus event is being called in an infinite loop.  This should be easy to verify

Comment: @Deczaloth the same thing happens in the latest version of X.Forms (4.4) and Android 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the Issue!

Thanks to @LeoZhu-MSFT for his insight!

The thing is that when `entry.Text = "3.00"` is set, this value is apparently parsed to double and then send to my property setter. In fact:

```
double _Weight = double.Parse("3.00"); // _Weight ends up having value 3!!!
```

So `entry.Text` and `_Weight` have always different values!!! and the **binding** tries to set indefinitely `_Weight` to `3.00` but all `_Weight` gets in the setter is `3`...

To solve that, instead of changing my property `_Weight` to **String** as suggested by @LeoZhu-MSFT, which is sub-optimal (i still want to perform mathematical operations with my `Weight` property!), i can change it to **decimal**!!!

In fact:

```
decimal _Weight = decimal.Parse("3.00"); // _Weight has now value 3.00. As wanted!!!
```

So after i change `_Weight` and `Weight` type to **decimal** in my **View Model**, the *infinite-loop-behavior* disappeared :D

Answer (score 3):

i test your codes,and debug it,i found it would infinite loop in

```
set
    {
        if (_Weight != value)
        {
            _Weight = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

i think it bescause your `Weight` property is `double` type,it could not set it as `string` correctly,you could try to define the Weight as string.

```
private string _Weight;
public string Weight
    {
        get => _Weight;
        set
        {
            if (_Weight != value)
            {
                _Weight = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You got my vote-up since you put me in the right direction. With your help i elaborated a more complete answer that i also posted. If you have anything to add, please let me know. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly because your unfocused handler sets the entry with the value entered causing a loop.

```
private void entry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    ((Entry)sender).Text = "1.0";
}
```

Comment: That is not the case. That handler is only called once :/

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to resolve this problem is to use a Converter

```
public class DecimalConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is decimal)
                return value.ToString();
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (decimal.TryParse(value as string, out var dec))
                return dec;
            return value;
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

`<Entry Text="{Binding Weight, Converter={StaticResource DecimalConverter}}" />`

that All :)