# String.format currency sum rounding issues

Tags: c#, rounding, truncate

So i've checked [Format currency without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180068/format-currency-without-rounding) and some other posts, but i'm not sure i'm finding my specific error anywhere.

**View**

```
@foreach (var item in attyData)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@String.Format("{0:C0}", item.cashMoney)</td>
    </tr>
}                
<tr class="info">   
    <td>@String.Format("{0:C0}", Model.attyData.Sum(item => item.cashMoney))</td>                    
</tr>
```

**Database Results for cashMoney**

```
12.2
13.3
```

**View Results**

```
$12
$13

Total Line - $26
```

How do I get my individual total line to not round?  Data type for cashMoney is `decimal?`

Comment: Is there a reason for excluding the decimal value from the view? One could argue that is the problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salami_slicing)

Comment: Couple good answers that ask a couple useful questions. 1. Do you want your total to be equal to the sum of the rounded values? i.e. do you want 12.2 (rounded to 12) + 13.3 (rounded to 13) to = 25 (sum of 12+13) or 26 (rounded result of the sum of 12.2 + 13.3)? Another way to think about this is what is your expected result of $10.40 + $10.40?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is correct. The `.Sum()` of 12.2 and 13.3 is 25.5, which rounds to 26 when the format is applied.

What you want to do instead is to sum as you iterate through your foreach loop:

```
@{ var total = 0; }

@foreach (var item in attyData)
{
    var cash = Math.Round(item.cashMoney);
    total += cash;
    <tr>
        <td>@String.Format("{0:C0}", cash)</td>
    </tr>
}                
<tr class="info">   
    <td>@String.Format("{0:C0}", total)</td>                    
</tr>
```

Comment: It's not the `.Sum()` causing the rounding; it's the format specifier.

Comment: @BlackFrog Clarified my comment to denote that `.Sum()` returns the value that the format specifier will round up.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want it rounded, use a different [Currency ("C") Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#CFormatString).

For example:

```
decimal a = 12.2M;
decimal b = 13.3M;

var sum = a + b;

Console.WriteLine($"C0 --- > {a,-8:C0} -- {b,-8:C0} -- {sum,-8:C0}");
Console.WriteLine($"C1 --- > {a,-8:C1} -- {b,-8:C1} -- {sum,-8:C1}");
Console.WriteLine($"C2 --- > {a,-8:C2} -- {b,-8:C2} -- {sum,-8:C2}");
Console.WriteLine($"C3 --- > {a,-8:C3} -- {b,-8:C3} -- {sum,-8:C3}");
```

Outputs the following:

```
C0 --- > $12      -- $13      -- $26
C1 --- > $12.2    -- $13.3    -- $25.5
C2 --- > $12.20   -- $13.30   -- $25.50
C3 --- > $12.200  -- $13.300  -- $25.500
```

[image]